# What does 'r' mean before a Regex pattern?

Tags: python, regex, string, syntax

I found the following regex substitution example from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for Regex. I'm a little bit confused as to what the prefix `r` does before the string?

```
re.sub(r'def\s+([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)\s*\(\s*\):',
 ...        r'static PyObject*\npy_\1(void)\n{',
 ...        'def myfunc():')
```

Comment: Ok I understand that it allows us have to have the `\n` processed as two separate chars and not as the single character. But why do Regexes prefer the former rather than the later. Can you explain that? e.g. I've often put a single blackslash to regex playgrounds like this one https://regex101.com/ without issues. When do regex want the raw string and why?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Placing `r` or `R` before a string literal creates what is known as a [raw-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) literal.  Raw strings do not process escape sequences (`\n`, `\b`, etc.) and are thus commonly used for Regex patterns, which often contain a lot of `\` characters.

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> print('\n') # Prints a newline character


>>> print(r'\n') # Escape sequence is not processed
\n
>>> print('\b') # Prints a backspace character

>>> print(r'\b') # Escape sequence is not processed
\b
>>>
```

The only other option would be to double every backslash:

```
re.sub('def\\s+([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)\\s*\\(\\s*\\):',
 ...        'static PyObject*\\npy_\\1(void)\\n{',
 ...        'def myfunc():')
```

which is just tedious.

Comment: Ok I understand that it allows us have to have the `\n` processed as two separate chars and not as the single character. But you didn't explain why Regexes prefer the former rather than the later. Can you explain that? e.g. I've often put a single blackslash to regex playgrounds like this one https://regex101.com/ without issues. When do regex want the raw string and why?

Answer (score 7):

The r means that the string is to be treated as a raw string, which means all escape codes will be ignored.

The [Python document](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) says this precisely:

> String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences.

Comment: Ok I understand that it allows us have to have the `\n` processed as two separate chars and not as the single character. But why do Regexes prefer the former rather than the later. Can you explain that? e.g. I've often put a single blackslash to regex playgrounds like this one https://regex101.com/ without issues. When do regex want the raw string and why?

Answer (score 0):

Current [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module docs gives explanation regarding raw-string usage

> Regular expressions use the backslash character (`'\'`) to indicate
> special forms or to allow special characters to be used without
> invoking their special meaning. This collides with Python’s usage of
> the same character for the same purpose in string literals; for
> example, to match a literal backslash, one might have to write `'\\\\'`
> as the pattern string, because the regular expression must be `\\`, and
> each backslash must be expressed as `\\` inside a regular Python string
> literal. Also, please note that any invalid escape sequences in
> Python’s usage of the backslash in string literals now generate a
> `DeprecationWarning` and in the future this will become a `SyntaxError`.
> This behaviour will happen even if it is a valid escape sequence for a
> regular expression.
>
> The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular
> expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in
> a string literal prefixed with `'r'`. So `r"\n"` is a two-character string
> containing `'\'` and `'n'`, while `"\n"` is a one-character string
> containing a newline. Usually patterns will be expressed in Python
> code using this raw string notation.

Comment: Ok I understand that it allows us have to have the `\n` processed as two separate chars and not as the single character. But why do Regexes prefer the former rather than the later. Can you explain that? e.g. I've often put a single blackslash to regex playgrounds like this one https://regex101.com/ without issues. When do regex want the raw string and why?