# Drop Duplicate Substrings from String with NO Spaces

Tags: python, pandas, string

Given a Pandas DF column that looks like this:

[image: Problem]

...how can I turn it into this:

```
XOM
ZM
AAPL
SOFI
NKLA
TIGR
```

Although these strings appear to be 4 characters in length maximum, I can't rely on that, I want to be able to have a string like `ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ` and still be able to turn it into `ABCDEFGHIJ` in one column calculation. Preferably WITHOUT `for` looping/iterating through the rows.

Comment: Does the repeating substring only appear twice? Is the repeated substring the entirety of the string, or can there be other characters around the repeated substrings?

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: @Chris Good question, yes it only repeats twice, and how it's displayed is exactly what it will be. So it's safe to assume that the entire string is a duplicate of itself, nothing more.

Comment: If that's the case, then you just need the first half of the string, no?

Comment: @Chris ....................you rock. I'm blind. I was struggling. But yes, that will work LOL thank you!

Comment: If you could guarantee that no character dublettes are in one sequence (AAPL suggest otherwise) than you could use binary tree like patricia-trie to solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regex` pattern like `r'\b(\w+)\1\b'` with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Symbol':['ZOMZOM', 'ZMZM', 'SOFISOFI', 
                             'ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ', 'NOTDUPLICATED']})
print(df['Symbol'].str.extract(r'\b(\w+)\1\b'))
```

Output:

```
           0
0         ZOM
1          ZM
2        SOFI
3  ABCDEFGHIJ
4         NaN # <- from `NOTDUPLICATED`
```

Explanation:

1. `\b` is a word boundary
2. `(w+)` capture a word
3. `\1` references to captured `(w+)` of the first group

Comment: could you please let me know why we `r` here? I thought `r` is used to make a string values be considered literally rather than considering `\` as special escape characters. But we don't have a special characters in the given column.

Comment: @KarthikS, Yes, Here, We want to say that string represents a formula of `regex`.

Comment: @KarthikS, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318287/what-does-r-mean-before-a-regex-pattern) we have a good explanation from other SO users: `String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences.`

Comment: OK, so `r` is used to make a formula a regex? Only then the regex engine works accordingly? Otherwise, `str.extract` will do just a literal matching without using regex formula?

Comment: @KarthikS, [Doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) says only for regex: `Extract capture groups in the regex pat as columns in a DataFrame.For each subject string in the Series, extract groups from the first match of regular expression pat.`

Comment: @KarthikS, we can use [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) for don't use `regex` with param=False and if want to use set param=True.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach which does involve iteration, but also regular expressions. Evaluate longest possible substrings first, getting progressively shorter. Use the substring to compile a regex that looks for the substring repeated two or more times. If it finds that, replace it with a single occurrence of the substring.

Does not handle leading or trailing characters. that are not part of the repetition.

When it performs a removal, it returns, breaking the loop. Going with longest substrings first ensures things like `'AAPLAAPL'` leave the double A intact.

```
import re

def remove_repeated(str):
    for i in range(len(str)):
        substr = str[i:]
        pattern = re.compile(f"({substr}){{2,}}")
        if pattern.search(str):
            return pattern.sub(substr, str)
    return str
```

```
>>> remove_repeated('abcdabcd')
'abcd'
>>> remove_repeated('abcdabcdabcd')
'abcd'
>>> remove_repeated('aabcdaabcdaabcd')
'aabcd'
```

If we want to make this more flexible, a helper function to get all of the substrings in a string, starting with the longest, but as a generator expression so we don't have to actually generate more than we need.

```
def substrings(str):
    return (str[i:i+l] for l in range(len(str), 0, -1) 
                       for i in range(len(str) - l + 1))
```

```
>>> list(substrings("hello"))
['hello', 'hell', 'ello', 'hel', 'ell', 'llo', 'he', 'el', 'll', 'lo', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

But there's no way `'hello'` is going to be repeated in `'hello'`, so we can make this at least somewhat more efficient by looking at only substrings at most half the length of the input string.

```
def substrings(str):
    return (str[i:i+l] for l in range(len(str)//2, 0, -1) 
                       for i in range(len(str) - l + 1))
```

```
>>> list(substrings("hello"))
['he', 'el', 'll', 'lo', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Now, a little tweak to the original function:

```
def remove_repeated(str):
    for s in substrings(str):
        pattern = re.compile(f"({s}){{2,}}")
        if pattern.search(str):
            return pattern.sub(s, str)
    return str
```

And now:

```
>>> remove_repeated('AAPLAAPL')
'AAPL'
>>> remove_repeated('fooAAPLAAPLbar')
'fooAAPLbar'
```

Comment: To handle an arbitrary number of repeats you can use `r'\b(\w+)\1+\b'` as regex ;)

Comment: I figured this might be instructive.

Comment: It's **is** instructive, probably not efficient however ;)

Comment: Bah! When were computer programmers ever worried about efficiency? ;)

Comment: Though an obvious efficiency improvement would be to start looking at substrings at longest half the length of the input string.